# Drawing a figure in PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,blkarray,multirow,graphics,amsthm,varioref,mathrsfs,amscd,amsopn,epsfig,fancyhdr,latexsym,makeidx,enumerate,titlesec,supertabular}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{pspicture}(3,2.5)
%\psgrid[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabels=10pt](0,0)(12,3)
\rput(3,0){

\psellipse(2,2)(1,.5)
\pscircle(2,1){.5}
\psdot(2,1.5)
\psdot(3,2)
\psdot(6,1.5)
\rput(2.75,2){$v_2$}
\rput(1.6,2.2){$G$}
\rput(2,1.7){$v_1$}
\rput(2,1.3){$u$}

\rput(2,.75){$H$}
\psellipse(6,2)(1,.5)
\pscircle(7.5,2){.5}
\psdot(7,2)

\rput(6.76,2){$v_2$}
\rput(5.6,2.2){$G$}
\rput(6,1.7){$v_1$}
\rput(7.2,2){$u$}


\rput(2,0){$G_1$}
\rput(6.5,1){$G_2$}
\rput(7.8,2){$H$}
}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{The graph $G_2$ is obtained from $G_1$ by relocating the branch $H$ at $u$ from $v_1$ to 
$v_2$.}\label{relocate-fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to run this code, but there is no outcome. Please help. There may be need of suitable package(s) but I am not getting. Please help.
output should be like this  : [image]

Comment: Could you include the entire file? There is no \documentclass line.

Comment: Is it ok now...?

Comment: You haven't actually included the package that defines `pspicture` :) Do you have `\usepackage{pstricks}` in your file?

Comment: I added pstricks to the \usepackage{...} list of packages. It compiles but the resulting graph is a mess (for me).

Comment: What is the resulting image intended to look like?

Comment: I have attach the out put of the graph. Please see

Comment: if you want to ask about the pstricks output please fix your example so it includes pstricks so people can run it.  Also remove the other packages which are not needed for the example. (No document written since 1993 should be using `epsfig` but none of the other packages are needed here either)

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
\usepackage{filecontents,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,blkarray,multirow,graphics,amsthm,varioref,mathrsfs,amscd,amsopn,epsfig,fancyhdr,latexsym,makeidx,enumerate,titlesec,supertabular}
```

by

```
\usepackage{pstricks}
```

so `pstricks` is loaded (none of the other packages are needed here, and `epsfig` should never be used at all, it is for emulating LaTeX2.09 documents from the 1980s)

then run `latex` (not pdflatex), `dvips` and `ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` and the resulting document is

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the outcome says undefined controll sequence \rput.

Comment: @user244706 it will not say that if you load pstricks

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1,-0.5)(8,2.5)
\psellipse(2,2)(1,.5)
\pscircle(2,1){.5}
\psdots(2,1.5)(3,2)(6,1.5)(7,2)
\uput[180](3,2){$v_2$}
\rput(1.6,2.2){$G$}
\uput[90](2,1.5){$v_1$}
\uput[-90](2,1.5){$u$}

\rput(2,.75){$H$}
\psellipse(6,2)(1,.5)
\pscircle(7.5,2){.5}

\uput[180](7,2){$v_2$}
\rput(5.6,2.2){$G$}
\uput[90](6,1.5){$v_1$}
\uput[0](7,2){$u$}

\rput(2,0){$G_1$}
\rput(6.5,1){$G_2$}
\rput(7.8,2){$H$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for Herbert, `PSTricks` is still alive forever ...